# Using then() on a failed promise?

Tags: javascript

I have a store method...

```
async store() {
      try {
         return await axios.post('/upload', data);
      } catch (error) {
               
      }
  },
```

Called by:

```
store().then(()=>{ console.log('ok'); }, ()=>{ console.log('not ok'); });
```

But when the store method fails and an error is caught, the first method in `then` is always called, how can I get the failed `not ok` method to be called?

Comment: `store` must fail; since you’re catching the exception without raising a new one, it never will. Simply remove the `try..catch`‽

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `throw` the error caught in the `catch` block of the `store` function

```
async store() {
    try {
       return await axios.post('/upload', data);
    } catch (error) {
       throw error;  
    }
}
```

You could also skip catching the error in the `store` function and simply catch it when `store` function is called. To do this, you just need to return the result of `axios.post(...)`.

```
async store() { 
   return axios.post('/upload', data);
}
```

*(Note that, without the `try-catch` block, you don't need an `await` before `axios.post(...)` because the promise returned by the `store` function will be *resolved* to the promise returned by `axios.post(...)`. This means that if the promise returned by `axios.post(...)` is fulfilled, promise returned by the `store` function will also fulfil with the same fulfilment value with which the promise returned by `axios.post(...)` fulfilled.)*

It is uncommon to pass second argument to `then` function. Instead, you should chain a `.catch()` block to catch the error.

```
store()
  .then(() => console.log('ok'))
  .catch(() => console.log('not ok'));
```

Comment: A trailing `.catch` would catch errors occurring in `.then`, which may or may not be what you want.