# React/Javascript Promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs

*Code Block 1*

```
export async function sendToDatabase(order, ownProps) {
    const url = `api_url`
    await axios.post(url, order).then(
      (response) => {
        if (response.status == 200){
        console.log("response 200")
        console.log(response)
        return response
        }
      }
    ).catch(error => (error))
}
```

*Code Block 2*

```
sendToDatabase(order, ownProps).then(
      value => console.log(value)
)
```

*Console Output*

```
response 200
{data: "Order Uploaded", status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
undefined
```

The function in code block 1 is called in code block 2. I don't really understand why the value returned is undefined, especially since the sendToDatabase() function returns a promise, and the promise should already be resolved in the then block

Also, due to certain constraints of my project, the 2 code blocks cannot be merged, and have to exist separately, hence I am not able to put code block 2 into the .then() block of code block 1

Any form of advice or help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to return from `sendToDatabase` function `return await ....`

Comment: `since the sendToDatabase() function returns a promise` it returns a Promise, but not the one created by axios.post()

Comment: You're not returning anything from sendToDatabase. If you return the result of the await call it should work.

Comment: There is no need to use `.then` in the first function. The whole point of using await is to make it look like synchronous code. `const response = await axios.post(url, order); if (..) return response else return ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a comment would be enough for such a question but i would like to post an answer as there are multiple problems in your code.

- `sendToDatabase` function doesn't explicitly returns any value, so the promise returned by it is implicitly fulfilled with the value of `undefined`.

  To fix this problem, you need to explicitly return some value from `sendToDatabase` function.
- Don't mix promise-chaining with `async-await` syntax. Your `sendToDatabase` function can be simplified as shown below:

  ```
  export async function sendToDatabase(order, ownProps) {
     const url = `api_url`;

     try {
        return await axios.post(url, order); 
     } (error) {
        // handle the error
     }
  }
  ```

  I have omitted the check for `response.status`, you could check the status code in the calling code.
- Inside the callback function of the `catch` method, you are *returning* the error object that was passed to the callback function as an argument; this will *implicitly* [convert promise rejection into promise fulfilment](https://blog.yousafkhan.me/common-promise-anti-patterns#converting-promise-rejection-in-to-fulfilment).

  To solve the problem, you need to *throw* the error object instead of *returning* it.

  ```
  .catch(error => { throw error });
  ```

  I suggest that you allow the calling code to catch and handle the error. This means that you should remove the `catch` block from the `sendToDatabase` function and add it in the code where you call the `sendToDatabase` function.

  If you add the `catch` handler in the calling code, then your function could be simplified as shown below:

  ```
  export async function sendToDatabase(order, ownProps) {
     const url = `api_url`;
     return axios.post(url, order); 
  }
  ```

  (if you are wondering why there is no `await` keyword before `axios.post(...)`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62740112/using-then-on-a-failed-promise/62740158#62740158) which contains an answer to this question.